# Can custom metadata type records be deployed from post-install script?

Tags: isv, postinstall

Looking at limitations of post install script there's no mention of CMDt's, but it also seems like post install stuff does get that much attention and given how many limitations CMDt's have - its wise to ask if it actually works?

Comment: You can include all the custom metadata type and its record in the package then why do you want to deploy them using a post-install script?

Comment: The script will convert certain records from Custom Settings to custom metadata types that are used by various customers.

Comment: To clarify, this will be a package upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it and in order to achieve it, there are 2 ways -

Include that code in the post-install class
Run that code through a script in each org's developer console

You can have a look at the following blog post where apex code is doing exactly what you need.

[How to create/update custom metadata record using apex (Lightning Component)](https://sfcure.com/2018/05/28/how-to-create-update-custom-metadata-record-using-apex-lightning-component/)